# `npm start` got a massive number of error messages

Tags: npm, saleor

I am setting up the Saleor storefront following [this document](https://docs.saleor.io/docs/2.11/developer/installation/windows#installing-the-storefront). However, after calling the command `npm start` on Windows CMD, there were a massive number of error messages popped up.

I am new to `npm` and unsure if I missed anything in the configuration.

Please let me know if you need more information. Any hints will be highly appreciated.

**Screenshot of the last a few error messages:**

1. The beginning part of screen output:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\my\work\saleor-dev\saleor-storefront> npm start

> saleor-site@3.0.0-a.0 start
> next dev -p 3000

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from C:\my\work\saleor-dev\saleor-storefront\.env.development
info  - Loaded env from C:\my\work\saleor-dev\saleor-storefront\.env
warn  - React 17.0.1 or newer will be required to leverage all of the upcoming features in Next.js 11. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-version
info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: future.webpack5 option disabled https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
Defining routes from exportPathMap
Warning: Reverting webpack devtool to 'inline-source-map'.
Changing the webpack devtool in development mode will cause severe performance regressions.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/improper-devtool
Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected.
See here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/built-in-css-disabled

info  - Using external babel configuration from C:\my\work\saleor-dev\saleor-storefront\babel.config.js
error - ./src/globalStyles/scss/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/globalStyles/scss/index.scss)
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
Issues checking in progress...
(node:14980) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'C:\my\work\saleor-dev\saleor-storefront\node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb-typescript\package.json' of 'dist/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
...
```

And then,

2. The error messages:

```
... a massive number of error messages omitted ...

ERROR in src/views/Search/SearchPage.tsx:114:14
prettier/prettier: Delete `␍`
    112 |             if (data && data.products === null) {
    113 |               return <NotFound />;
  > 114 |             }
        |              ^
    115 |
    116 |             if (!isOnline) {
    117 |               return <OfflinePlaceholder />;

ERROR in src/views/Search/SearchPage.tsx:115:1
prettier/prettier: Delete `␍`
    113 |               return <NotFound />;
    114 |             }
  > 115 |
        | ^
    116 |             if (!isOnline) {
    117 |               return <OfflinePlaceholder />;
    118 |             }

ERROR in src/views/Search/SearchPage.tsx:116:29
prettier/prettier: Delete `␍`
    114 |             }
    115 |
  > 116 |             if (!isOnline) {
        |                             ^
    117 |               return <OfflinePlaceholder />;
    118 |             }
    119 |           }}

ERROR in src/views/Search/SearchPage.tsx:117:45
prettier/prettier: Delete `␍`
    115 |
    116 |             if (!isOnline) {
  > 117 |               return <OfflinePlaceholder />;
        |                                             ^
    118 |             }
    119 |           }}
    120 |         </TypedSearchProductsQuery>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you may have edited the file under Windows, which uses CR+LF as end-of-line. And you have configured prettier (or by using a template, by default) set prettier to check if end-of-line is LF (unix style end-of-line), and report incorrect formatting as an error.

More about newline: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

## Solution

You can either set prettier to allow the CR+LF line ending, or convert every source file to use LF line ending.

### allow CR+LF line ending

You should try finding this section in `eslintrc`:

```json
'prettier/prettier': [
  'error',
  {
    'endOfLine': '[something something]',
  }
]
```

and change the 'endOfLine' line to this:

```json
    'endOfLine': 'auto',
```

or

```json
    'endOfLine': 'crlf',
```

Either of these should allow CR+LF to be used.

### convert CR+LF to LF (recommended)

You can do it manually in your editor, or you can let prettier do it.
In your project folder, create `.prettierrc.json` (it may already exist if you are using a template, if it does, edit the existing one inst).

Set this option in `.prettierrc.json`:

```json
{
    "endOfLine": "lf"
}
```

Then run `npx prettier --write src/` for npm or `yarn prettier --write src/` for yarn.

After that, you can run `npx prettier --check src/` to check if the source files are formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the program:

dos2unix infile outfile and vice versa (unix2dos) for stripping line feeds.